# File I/O Code in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2010, file-io, text-files

So I've been up for a long time now and maybe thats why I can't figure this out. But my code here will work only on the first execution, i.e., since there is a menu with about 4 options, it will work only for the one that is selected first. When the do while loop kicks in and the menu is displayed again, no matter what you select, it keeps re displaying the menu. I have analyzed the do while loop but am pretty sure there aren't any problems with that. I've only recently started learning about File I/O so maybe there's something I missed. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Here's the code:

**Phonebook.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Phone
{ 
public:
void display_phonebook(ifstream& in_stream);// phonebook is the text file 
void display_backup(string a[], int size);// backup copy is a string array
void datacopy(ifstream& in_stream, string a[]);// to copy the phonebook to the array
int numberOfLines(ifstream& in_stream);// to check number of lines in the text file
};
```

**Phonebook.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include "Phonebook.h"

using namespace std;

void Phone::datacopy(ifstream& in_stream, string a[])
{
int i=0;
while(in_stream.good())
{
    string line;
    getline(in_stream, line);
    a[i]=line;
    i++;
}
int s=i;
for(int x=0;x<s;x++)
{
    cout<<a[x]<<endl;
}
}


int Phone::numberOfLines(ifstream& in_stream)
{
int count=0;
while(!in_stream.eof())
{
    string line;
    getline(in_stream, line);
    count++;
}
return count;
}

void Phone::display_phonebook(ifstream& in_stream)
{
while(!in_stream.eof())
{
    string line;
    getline(in_stream, line);
    cout<<line<<endl;
}
}

void Phone::display_backup(string a[], int size)
{
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    cout<<a[i]<<endl;
}
cout<<endl;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include "Phonebook.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
Phone p;
int size=0;
ifstream fin;
ofstream fout;
char file[50], ch;
string backup[50];
int flag=0;
do
{
    cout<<"Enter the name of the file: "<<endl;
    cin>>file;
    fin.open(file);
    cout<<endl;
    if(fin.fail())
    {
        cout<<"File not found!"<<endl<<endl;
        cout<<"Try Again? (Y/N)"<<endl;
        cin>>ch;
        if(ch=='N' || ch=='n')
        {
            cout<<"Terminating..."<<endl;
            system("PAUSE");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        flag=1;
    }
}
while((ch=='Y' || ch=='y') && flag==0);
cout<<"Success! File Opened"<<endl<<endl;
int choice;
do
{
    cout<<"1 - Display phonebook"<<endl;
    cout<<"2 - Display backup copy"<<endl;
    cout<<"3 - Update backup copy"<<endl;
    cout<<"4 - Exit"<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter your choice:  ";
    cin>>choice;
    if(choice==1)
    {
        p.display_phonebook(fin);
    }
    else if(choice==2)
    {
        size=p.numberOfLines(fin);
        p.display_backup(backup, size);
    }
    else if(choice==3)
    {
        p.datacopy(fin, backup);
    }
} 
while(choice!=4);
fin.close();
fout.close();
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Generally an enormous code dump like this is not the way to get help from Stack Overflow. Surely you can pare this down to a minimal example that shows the problem. And if you solve it while you're doing that, then good for you!

Comment: Which while loop is troubling you? I counted 5 in your code.

Comment: @Stencil @jrok: He means the do while loop with the literal `"1 - Display phonebook"`.  The direct cause is the stream got in a bad state, but it's not immediately obvious _why_ it's in a bad state.

Comment: I'm sorry abt the massive code guys bt I'm new to Stack Overflow and just wanted to be thorough. Bt yea, the trouble is happening within the last do-while loop as @MooingDuck suggested. Pretty sure its nt the loop though. Maybe something to do with the buffers that everyone else suggested. I'm gonna look into it more and get back to you guys. Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: [See OP answer for TL close reason](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10508286/50776).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You shouldn't post this much code. You should post a minimal complete example; that is, whittle down the code as much as you can while still generating the bad behavior. Eventually either the bug will become obvious or you'll arrive at something much smaller and simpler for us to comb through.

2) You're too exhausted to remove all the irrelevant code? No problem, just don't write it in the first place. Start small, build up, test at every stage, and **never add to code that doesn't work**. You should never have let the code get this big without discovering the problem.

3)

```
void Phone::display_phonebook(ifstream& in_stream)
{
  while(!in_stream.eof())
    {
      string line;
      getline(in_stream, line);
      cout<<line<<endl;
    }
}
```

This will display the contents of the file *once*. Then the file stream is at the end of the file, like staring at the back cover of a book. When you call the function again, it gives you nothing more. You must either store the contents of the file in a variable, or close and reopen the stream (or rewind, but that's a more advanced technique, not recommended).

Comment: This may not even display it correctly once.  It attempts to read a line, then uses the results, whether the read succeeds or not.  The loop should be `std::string line; while ( std::getline( in_stream, line ) ) { std::cout << line << std::endl; }`

Comment: +1 Step 2 is very important. Incremental changes with incremental testing FTW!

Comment: @JamesKanze, you're right, but this whole function will have to be revamped or scrapped anyway. And there may be other problems elsewhere in the code; I was just pointing out the cause of the most obvious misbehavior.

Comment: You're most probably right @Beta and I wanted to clarify that it was working before I started more operations on the stream. Probably something to do with the case that the stream is now at the end of the file as you suggested. I'm gonna try this approach and get back to you guys. Appreciate the help :)

Comment: Well, thanks everyone for your suggestions. But yeah, the problem was that the input stream was stuck at the end of the file when the control passed to the second function. The simplest fix was to close and reopen the stream after the stream reached the end of the file and that's what I employed. Also, I came to know a lot about other stuff from you guys which will help me become a better coder (I hope!). Also, will definitely look into some exception handling for the code (Thanks @James Kanze). Alright, happy coding everyone.

Answer (score 3):

So one thing to note is that when you send the ifstream into a function and call getline the "buffer" is advanced. So you cant reread that line without opening the buffer again. You need to reorganize your code to account for this, or save the data from the file internally instead of trying to reread it during displaying.

Comment: Hmm... I think you probably are right. I'm gonna try this approach. Thanks a lot dude.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with your code.

The reason your code only "works" once is because you read the file to
completion the first time, leaving the input at end of file, so further
reads will fail.  You should either read the file completely into memory
up front, then pass the image (probably an `std::vector<std::string>` to
the various functions, or you should create a new `std::ifstream` object
in each of the functions, as a local variable (and not have an 
`std::ifstream` object in the main loop).  Otherwise, you'll have to
clear the error and seek to the beginning of the stream before each
function.

Another thing your doing is using `in_stream.good()` or
`!in_stream.eof()` as the control condition of the loop.  And then, at
least in `datacopy` and `display_phonebook`, using the string read by
`std::getline` without verifying that the `std::getline` succeeded.
Typically, this will result in the last line being processed twice.
`std::istream::good()` is a worthless function, and `st::istream::eof()`
is only interesting *after* you've detected failure.  The correct way to
write your loops is:

```
std::string line;
while ( std::getline( in_stream, line ) ) {
    //  ...
}
```

`Phone::datacopy` has undefined behavior (and will probably crash) if
the input file has more the 50 lines.  Use `std::vector<std::string>`
here, clearing it at the top of the function, and then calling
`push_back` for each line read.

You'll also want to do some error handling when reading the command.  If
the user inputs an `'a'`, for example, you'll go into an endless loop.
I'd probably use `std::getline` for the interactive input as well,
parsing the line separately.  That way, the actual input doesn't go into
an error status which has to be cleared if the user inputs junk.  (And
if he enters something like `"Display phonebook"`, you don't have two
worry about getting rid of all of the excess characters in the input.)

Finally, if you define a user class `Line`, with an `operaator>>` which
uses `getline`, most of your functions will reduce to a single call to
`std::copy`, using and `std::istream_iterator<Line>`.

Oh, and you can use a `switch` instead of the `if/else if` chain.

Comment: I managed to get it working but I'll certainly keep these points in mind for the future. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, thanks everyone for your suggestions. But yeah, the problem was that the input stream was stuck at the end of the file when the control passed to the second function. The simplest fix was to close and reopen the stream after the stream reached the end of the file and that's what I employed. Also, I came to know a lot about other stuff from you guys which will help me become a better coder (I hope!). Also, will definitely look into some exception handling for the code (Thanks @James Kanze). Alright, happy coding everyone.